# Matlab equivalent of Python scipy.optimize.fmin_cg

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

Is there a matlab equivalent for Python's `scipy.optimize.fmin_cg` function?
I am using Matlab R2008a, and python 2.6.

Background: I want to translate the following snippet from Python to Matlab

```
retval = optimize.fmin_cg(hsic.ObjUnBiasedHSIC,sga[[k],].ravel(),\
                          hsic.GradUnBiasedHSIC,args=[x,kernelx,L,sL,ssL],\
                          gtol=1e-6, maxiter=100,full_output=True, disp=False)
```

If someone could post the exact translation with the correct optimset, it'd be super!!!

All help greatly appreciated..
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at fminsearch?

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fminsearch.html

Comment: Note that `fminsearch` is based on [Nelder-Mead downhill simplex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder–Mead_method) and thus is more analogous to Scipy's [`scipy.optimize.fmin`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fmin.html) I imagine. However, it'll likely work fine though you won't be able to specify a gradient via `optimset` because Nelder-Mead doesn't use them. If you need gradients, try `fminunc` -the large-scale algorithm is even [based on conjugate gradient methods](http://mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/unconstrained-nonlinear-optimization-algorithms.html).